# Requirements to boot a rootfs.img

Tags: linux, boot-loader, bootable, disk-image

I have a Linux image from which I've extracted a "rootfs.img" file, the file seems to contain files and information, I would like to "boot into it" 
file contents: 
`bin
dev
etc
home
lib
media
mnt
proc
run
sbin
service
sys
tmp
usr
var
lib64`

how can I install a bootloader to boot it?

I've tried:
getting a live ubuntu image, adding a partition, placing the contents of rootfs.img inside the partition and running "Boot Repair", which did find the other system as another bootable linux, but I can't boot into it, seems like I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Since the image doesn't contains any `boot` directory, it's probably missing both bootloader and kernel.

1. Take any device you have and that is bootable using your computer (flash drive, external hard drive, etc...)
2. From a linux computer, run as root  `dd if=rootfs.img of=<your device>`
3. When `dd` ends, run (still as root):

   1. `mount <your device> <some location of your choice>`
   2. `mount -o bind /proc <some location of your choice>/proc`
   3. `mount -o bind /sys <some location of your choice>/sys`
4. Then, run (root, again) `chroot <the mountpoint> bash`
5. At this step, you're running `bash` with the content of rootfs.img as root filesystem. You can now:

   1. `mkdir /boot`
   2. Install a Linux kernel.
   3. Install the bootloader of your choice (`grub`, `lilo`, `syslinux`, ...)
   4. Configure the bootloader to get installed on your device.

Once all this steps are achieved, you should have your rootfs.img on your external device with a bootloader on it. Just reboot and boot from the external device.
That's it.

Comment: should all of this be possible using a VM?, for exmaple instead of the "2.", just import the disk to a VM?

Comment: Sure, but your image is still missing a kernel and a bootloader... To work directly on the `.img` file, you can mount it directly using the `mount -o loop rootfs.img <mountpoint>`

Comment: ok, I did the above, and seems that I do have a /boot which contains the following:

`EFI  bzImage-3.10.62-ltsi      vmlinux-3.10.62-ltsi
bzImage  bzImage-3.10.62-ltsi-crash
`